# Is there an easy way to change the font and size for Chapter Heading in Memoir?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir, fontsize, chapters

I'm a total TeX newb - please be nice!  :-)

How can I change the font and size of Chapter headings?  I don't mind where it's placed on the page - but would like it to be a sans-serif font and perhaps a bit bigger?  These are un-named chapters... they just need to say Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc.

I tried to post pictures of my code and the results but the forum said I have to earn 10 reputation points to post images.  :-(

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}


\input{chapter01.tex}

\input{chapter02.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome and I will try removing the ! next time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Choose the `section` chapter style and redefine the macros `\chapnumfont` and `\chaptitlefont`. See section 6.5 of the `memoir` manual for details. (Note: The `\HUGE` fontsize switch isn't available in the standard classes.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{section}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\sffamily}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, you could redefine `\printchaptertitle` to gobble its argument (here: not print "First chapter" at all):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As cfair has commmented, I have replaced the obsolete `palatino` package with [`mathpazo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo).

Comment: Okay.. thanks - I've got it looking a little more like I want it to using your suggestions.  Is there a way to be able to specify a font by name?

Comment: @Gretchen You'd have to use XeLaTeX (a LaTeX variant with easier font handling) for that -- I'm not versed in XeLaTeX, though. Have a look at the [tag:xetex] tag.

Comment: Hmmmm since I BARELY grasp what the heck I'm doing in LaTeX I might just hold off on looking at XeLaTeX....

Comment: @Gretchen If you regard my answer as helpful, please upvote and accept it. Alternatively, you can edit your question to include more details. For follow-up questions ask a new question.