# Package "comicsans": How to prevent setting of default fonts

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I'm using the comicsans package and I noticed that it automatically changes a lot of default fonts to comics.

I was wondering if there is some command to restore everything to the default fonts?

I've already tried

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
```

The problem is the comicsans package change a lot of font families, so I would like to avoid setting everything manually to the right font (actually I don't which are the default fonts for book document) and use comic font only for few paragraph where it is needed.

Comment: The package changes maths as well as text fonts. (Why does it set comic**sans** as the default **roman** font?) If you only want to use comicsans for a small amount of text, this is a duplicate of the question Adam linked to. If not, you would need to be a lot more explicit about what you want to use the font for. You can override the settings but that will put you back to square one i.e. no point in loading the package in the first place. So presumably, you want to use it for something... what exactly? Just text? Maths? Both?

Comment: See also my remarks at the end of my answer: [Installing the comicsans package to MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79805).

Comment: Sorry, it is impossible to resist. Try to visit this webpage: http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/ –– I mean, depending on what you want to do, Comic Sans _might_ be a good choice, but very easily it _may be not_.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: comic sans is *not* a default font in all distributions and so it is not always just a matter of finding the family name and selectively using it.  This question is worthy of an answer; and the easiest answers will be those that utilize XeTeX and/or LuaTeX.  (Unrelated, but `comicsans.sty` does, by design, set the font as the default font.)

Comment: @tohecz Giving Kill KRT the benefit of the doubt, he surely is writing an anti-Comic Sans pamphlet in LaTeX. But yeah, I also read no further than "I'm using the comicsans package" before I thought "WRONG!" ;)

Comment: In defence of the font, I used to write all of my documents in it because I found it easy to read on screen. That is, the actual documents used Latin Modern (mostly) but my source was all comicsans. (I figured if I found it easy to read on screen it was really nobody's business but mine.) I find monospace easier now, though, so comicsans isn't an option - and I have switched to Linux in any case.

Comment: @Christian ;-) No, I'm not writing an anti-comic pamphlet, just using Comic Sans for writing "dumb questions" sessions where I put Homer avatar (from Simpsons package) to ask stupid questions written in Comics! :-)

Comment: @KillKRT Well then maybe you should consider one of the free alternatives from http://bancomicsans.com/main/?page_id=98 There are a lot of fonts that just don't have that immediate cringe factor that Comic Sans has for many people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best would be, if you’d avoid loading the package. And also it is a bad idea to use this font for longer text parts. Comic Sans once [was developed for Comics](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typefaces/story-of-comic-sans) – hence the name – where the text is usually short. In my eyes it is depending on the context sometimes tolerable in headings, for instance in texts for children. On the other hand it is over used. See also [Comic Sans Criminal - There's help available for people like you!](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/).

Instead do one of the following things:

- If you need the Type1 version define these two commands *without loading the package*

  ```
  \newcommand*{\cmcsans}{\fontfamily{comic}\selectfont}
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcmcsans}{\cmcsans}
  ```

  and use this in the same way, as you would do with `\sffamily` (conforms to `\cmcsans`) and `\textsf` (conforms to `\textcmcsans`) and companions. To say this once again explicitly: *This works without loading of the package `comicsans`, as long as it is correctly installed.*
- You could also install [`winfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/winfonts) into a local root (cf. [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)). This package makes several TrueType fonts installed in the Windows system available for pdfTeX. But see next point and note the warning in the documentation of this package:

  > With these fonts, the T1 encoding is not not [sic!] complete: some glyph are missing, depending on the font. … You should test closely a font before using it for productive works.

  <sup>*See perhaps ‘[The usage of “sic” in writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28935/)’.*</sup>

  I do not know, whether this is valid for the Comic Sans part, too, and if this also relates to the fact, that the TrueType version of Comic Sans lacks font files for italic (or slanted) and bold italic.
- Instead of this second approach TrueType/OpenType fonts are better directly available with LuLaTeX and XeLaTeX using the package `fontspec` (this may be loaded in background by another package, most notably `luatextra` and `xltxtra`). Create a new font family and define again the corresponding text font command as above

  ```
  \newfontfamily\cmcsans{Comic Sans MS}
  % if there are problems with this variant use this one instead:
  % \newfontfamily\cmcsans[BoldFont=comicbd.ttf]{comic.ttf}
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcmcsans}{\cmcsans}
  ```

  And again this could be used like `\sffamily` or `\textsf`.

Some links at the end, if you want to change the titles:

It is most easy with KOMA-Script classes, cf. [KOMA-Script: change font of sectioning headings to serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25845/koma-script-change-font-of-sectioning-headings-to-serif).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand*{\cmcsans}{\fontfamily{comic}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcmcsans}{\cmcsans}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\cmcsans}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

For `memoir` see this for a start: [Changing font size of chapter headings the same as that of section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135852/changing-font-size-of-chapter-headings-the-same-as-that-of-section) and [Is there an easy way to change the font and size for Chapter Heading in Memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80558/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-font-and-size-for-chapter-heading-in-memoir).

For standard classes see this one [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti).

Comment: Thank you, so basically my solution has been removing the \usepackage{comicsans} since I had already created a command as you suggested. I'm a little newbie, I didn't know that \usepackage is not necessary to use external fonts.

Comment: @KillKRT: Yes, it is usually not _necessary_, but in most cases it is also for fonts better to load the respective package. Simply take a look into the package files (with `.sty` extension) for some fonts. You would have needed to put most of this code into your document preamble (though the package author must have different use cases in mind, while you probably need only a part of this).